# MDX Query for T-SQL

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am new to mdx, can anyone please help me what would be the mdx query for the below t-sql

```
SELECT count(distinct rf.PatientID), (d.FiscalYearLong) as fiscalyear from  [dbo].[ReferralFact] rf
 join [Dim].[Date] d 
 on rf.ReferralDateID = d.DateID
 group by  d.FiscalYearLong
 ORDER BY fiscalyear DESC
```

Comment: It's not easy to tell unless you show how your cube looks like. Alternatively, show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of what is available within your cube this is pure guesswork, but it might look something like the following:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[NumPatientID] ON COLUMNS, 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS 
FROM [YourCube];
```

A date dimension would usually have ordering built in so no need for any explicit use of the `mdx` function `ORDER`.

Also it is better if well used measures are calculated within the cube, so I have assumed your BI developer has created a measure equivalent to `count(distinct rf.PatientID)` which is referenced using `[Measures].[NumPatientID]`

Comment: yes the cube has a count(distinct rf.PatientID) in the measures, but the only trouble I am facing is the group by, i need the distinct count of patients in each fiscal year, is that possible?

Comment: ideally you need to add a fiscal year hierarchy into your date dimension